If $B \supseteq A$ are unitary commutative rings, $B$ is Noetherian, and there exists an $A$-linear retraction $r: B \to A$, then is $A$ Noetherian?
If $B\supseteq A$ are unitary commutative rings, $B$ is Noetherian, and there exists an $A$-linear retraction $r: B \to A$, then is $A$ Noetherian?
By an $A$-linear retraction I mean that $r$ is a morphism of $A$-modules, though not necessarily of rings, such that $r|_A = id_A$.
The answer is apparently yes, but I haven't quite been able to prove it. I have got to the decomposition of $B$ as an $A$-module as $B = \ker(r) \oplus A$, but I haven't been able to show that $B$ is a Noetherian $A$-module which would imply $A$ also is. This last step comes from using a short exact sequence
$$0\to\ker(r)\overset{i}{\to} B \overset{r}{\to} A\to 0.$$
I have also tried to show that as ideal $I$ of $A$ are finitely generated by considering $r^{-1}(I)$ in $\ker(r)\oplus A$.
How would you complete the proof?

Potential Solution:
With much effort, I managed to squeeze what seems to be a valid solution out of ChatGPT.
Consider an ideal $I$ of $A$. We wish to see that it is finitely generated. Let $J = (I) = IB$, the ideal generated by $I$ in $B$. As $B$ is a Noetherian ring, there exist $b_1,...,b_k\in B$ such that $J = ( b_1,....,b_n)$. However, each $b_i$ itself is in the ideal generated by $I$ and hence each is a $B$-linear combination of elements of $I$. Therefore this finite set of elements of $I$, $S =\{s_1,...,s_n\}\subset I$, which generates the $b_i$s also generates $J$ which contains I.
For any $b\in J$ we have $b = \sum_{i=1}^N c_is_i$ for some $c_i\in B$. Then we know $r(b) = \sum_{i=1}^N s_i r(c_i)$ by the $A$-linearity of $r$. Because $r(J) \supseteq I$, and $r(J) \subseteq SA \subseteq I$, we conclude that $r(J) = I$ and that $S$ generates $I$ in $A$. Every ideal of $A$ is finitely generated, hence $A$ is Noetherian.

Welcome to Math Stackexchange. Nice question! It's considered good practice to repeat the information in the title  in the body of the post, so people don't have to rely on the title to understand what you're asking. Also, I think you forgot to mention that $A$ is a subring of $B$?

Pick an increasing sequence of ideals $(I_n){n\geq 1}$ in $A$. Then $(J_n){n\geq 1}=(r^{-1}(I_n)){n\geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence of ideals in $B$. As $B$ is noetherian we know that $(J_n){n\geq 1}$ becomes stationary. Then use the fact that $r$ is surjective to conclude that $(I_n)_{n\geq 1}$ becomes stationary too (and therefore $A$ is noetherian).

@AlexKruckman you are right, A is a subring. Thank you for the advice.

@SeverinSchraven how do you know that the $r^{-1}(I_n)$ are ideals? We only have an $A$-linear retraction which isn't necessarily a ring homomorphism. An example of an $A$-linear retraction which isn't a homomorphism of rings is $r:\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$ which projects to the real part.

@JoshL. It was not clear to me in which category you are working in and I (falsely) assumed all of them to be ring homomorphisms. Sorry for that.

@SeverinSchraven No worries. It was a bit vague, and so I have clarified in the post.

Shockingly, the ChatGPT solution is the right idea. As you may know, the problem with ChatGPT is that is can write math that looks plausible and well-written at first glance, but almost always turns out to be complete nonsense. I cannot recommend strongly enough that you do not try to use ChatGPT to learn mathematics!
In this case, you've found a correct solution. I would write the second paragraph more simply, though. Once we've found a finite set $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}\subseteq I$ which generates $J$ as an ideal of $B$, we claim that $S$ generates $I$ as an ideal of $A$.
So let $x\in I$. Since $x\in J$, there exists $b_1,\dots,b_n\in B$ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^n b_is_i$. Then $$x=r(x)=r\left(\sum_{i=1}^n s_ib_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n s_ir(b_i).$$
Since each $r(b_i)\in A$, we see that $S$ generates $I$ as an idea of $A$.

ChatGPT has got better but I agree it is far from perfect. I had to keep on pointing out the mistakes in its solutions until it finally got there.
You've made the solution a lot more elegant though, thanks!
